# Diagonal pan with jquery.spritely

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to pan in a diagonal direction (eg. down-left) with [Spritely](http://spritely.net/)? This is my current code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').pan({fps: 30, speed: 1, dir: 'left'});
});
```